# How to get depth value from scene cordinates by calling gluUnproject twice(not using gluUnProject)

Tags: c++, opengl

In [this](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/170900-Getting-real-world-coordinates-from-screen) thread. The second answer suggest that :

> Solution 2 call the `gluUnproject` two time, one with `clipZ = -1` and
>   another one with `clipZ = 1`, you get two point (in world space). With
>   these two point you get a ray and you can use some raycast algorithm
>   to compute the mouse coordinate.

But unfortunately it is not explained there after the suggestion. 
There is also this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25938924/get-mouse-in-world-coordinates-with-2-gluunproject-calls-to-create-ray) which explains a direction can be get by calling `gluUnproject` twice. Getting a direction makes sense to me but my question is how can I get the depth info by calling `gluUnProject` twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't get depth info. You only have a X and a Y, but to unproject you need a Z. And no magic is going to give it. Instead try to deduce it.

After you undo the viewport transform you have X,Y in NDC. What Z? Use `z1= 1` and X, Y. Unproject. Now you have a point P1 in world coordinates. Repeat Unproject but this time with `z2= -1`. You get P2. Likely you have to deal with forth 'w' coordinate. Remember you can extract 3D coordinates after dividing by w. In homogeneous coordinates w is a scale factor.

With P1 and P2 perhaps you can find on your own the intersection between line P1P2 and your model.

`z= -1, 1` are most separated coordinates in NDC, so more accurate the calculation results.

Comment: Ok that make sense. In the first link i feel like it was saying we can find the Z value just like readPixel. One more question if my model does not intersects?

Comment: If your model does not intersect then you are setting the mouse over an empty area.

Comment: Ripl2 I hope you saw my other question you commented it as well. I am not looking for selection I am trying to determine zooming level instead.